# jison rule precedence doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, grammar, operator-precedence, jison

I am now sitting multiple hours in front of a problem that seems rather simple to solve but i just cant get behind it :/

I am defining a small javascript-like language in jison. The problem is that the Parameter rule and the AssignStatement rule both (can) start with an CHAR_SEQUENCE and it always chooses the parameter rule. E.g. even though the code is `a = 5;` it reaches the `throw "reached parameter";` so it seems to parse the `a` as a Parameter instead of `a = 5;` as an AssignStatement

the relevant part of my grammar:

```
Parameter
    : InlineVariable
        { $$ = $1; }
    | CHAR_SEQUENCE
        { throw "reached parameter"; checkUndefined($1, @1); $$ = vars[$1]; }
    ;

InlineVariable
    : NUMBER
        { $$ = new Runtime.Integer(parseInt($1)); }
    | '"' CHAR_SEQUENCE '"'
        { $$ = new Runtime.String($2); }
    | FUNCTION '(' ParameterList ')' Statement
        { $$ = new Container($5); }
    ;

AssignStatement
    : CHAR_SEQUENCE AssignmentOperator Parameter ';'
        {
            $$ = function()
            {
                if((typeof vars[$1] == 'undefined' && $3 instanceof Runtime.Integer) || (vars[$1] instanceof Container && $3 instanceof Runtime.Integer))
                    vars[$1] = new Runtime.Integer(0, $1);
                else if(typeof vars[$1] == 'undefined' || (vars[$1] instanceof Container && !($3 instanceof Container)))
                    vars[$1] = $3.constructor.call();

                $2(vars[$1], vars[$3]);
            }
        }
    | CHAR_SEQUENCE SingleAssignmentOperator ';'
        {
            $$ = function()
            {
                if(typeof vars[$1] == 'undefined')
                    vars[$1] = new Runtime.Integer(0, $1);

                $2(vars[$1]);
            };
        }
    ;
```

I posted the full grammar at https://gist.github.com/M4GNV5/36c2550946c1a1f6ec91

So is there a way to solve this problem? I of course already tried using %left, %right, %assoc and %precedence but it didnt work (or i did something wrong?

Comment: There is no `Assignment` production. If you mean `AssignmentStatement`, then I don't see anywhere that `AssignmentStatement` and `Parameter` are both viable. What exactly do you observe which leads you to your problem description?

Comment: yeah sorry i ment AssignStatement
the problem is that if i e.g. add an throw statement to the second Parameter rule it reaches this statement so it parses the `i` of `i = 5;` as an Parameter instead an AssingStatement
I updated the question

Comment: The reduction of `5` to `Parameter` is expected; it has nothing to do with `i`. I tried to explain in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the flow control in a bottom-up parser.

Actions are executed when the associated production is reduced (i.e. fully recognized), which won't happen until after all non-terminals in the production have been reduced.

The `AssignmentStatement` production is:

```
AssignStatement
    : CHAR_SEQUENCE AssignmentOperator Parameter ';'
```

So before its associated action can be executed, the productions for `AssignmentOperator` and `Parameter` must be executed. In this case, `Parameter` is matching the `5`.

Comment: when i replace the throw statement with `throw $1` it gave me `a` not `5` furthermore 5 should have been NUMBER>InlineVariable>Parameter so your answer isnt quite helpfull :/

anyways i defined FunctionDefinition as `FUNCTION CHAR_SQUENCE '(' CHAR_SQUENCE ParameterList ')' Block` and ParameterList as `',' CHAR_SQUENCE ParameterList` it might not be the best solution but its an workaround that at least... works ^^

Comment: @M4GNV5: OK, I'm glad you found a workaround. I still don't see anything in the snippet you posted where `Parameter` could match the `i` in an `AssignmentStatement` given the input `i = 5;`. If that's just part of the input, it might apply to some other part of the grammar you don't show. I didn't see any other kind of statement which might start with a `parameter`.

Comment: @M4GNV5 Furthermore, I took the grammar from your gist, fixed the lexer to recognize `<` and some other single-character tokens, fixed the missing `AdditionalParameter` non-terminal (by changing it to `ParameterList ','`, removed all the actions, and then successfully (and afaics correctly) parsed `i = 5;` and `if (i > 7) i = 5;` using `alert` in the `Parameter` rule to signal reductions. So if there is something not working, you'll need to be clearer about your example, your grammar, and your test.